# Injection vs. Surjection: Mnemonic to remember which is which

Tags: terminology, mnemonic

What are some mnemonics to help one remember that Injection = One-to-one and Surjection = Onto? The only thing I can think of is 1njection = 1-1.

Comment: I blame bad terminology. Until someone explains *why* these are called what they are called, I blame bad terminology.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I think it’s great terminology. See the answer by fgp.

Comment: It is not bad terminology. One only needs to know one Latin language.

Comment: @k.stm Not latin again. -.- at least now it makes sense. Btw I already saw that answer and upvoted.

Comment: @Sabyasachi “terminology” is Latin! : – D (and Ancient Greek, of course.)

Comment: Practice any concept enough, and the terminology settles down in your mind.

Comment: Not a mnemonic, but check out this [related math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202132/injection-and-surjection-origin-of-words)

Comment: @SergioParreiras Not Latin, one needs to know bourbakian.

Answer (score 27):

An *injection* $A \to B$ maps $A$ *into* $B$, i.e. it allows you to find a copy of $A$ inside $B$.

A *surjection* $A \to B$ maps $A$ *over* $B$, in the sense that the image covers the whole of $B$. The syllable "sur" has latin origin, and means "over" or "above", as for example in the word "surplus" or "survey".

Comment: Addendum: To be clear, “[sur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sur#French)” is *French* from Latin “super”.

Comment: @k.stm: That's super! Err, I mean... That's sur..! :-P

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at this picture (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Surjection.svg)):

[image: ][2]][2]]

This function is NOT injection, because two arrows point into single point in that picture.

Now imagine injections at the doctor. Injections usually hurt and you, sure as hell, woudln't want anyone to stick that injection into the same point on your body multiple times.

So that's why injective functions cannot have multiple arrows pointing into the same point (value)

:)

Answer (score 5):

The way I remember it is that when you get a flu shot your entire body doesn't turn into a giant flu virus, because the needle is smaller than your arm is. Then you can easily remember surjection as "the other one".

Another one is that **in**-jections are **in**-ferior and **su**-rjections are **su**-perior.

Comment: This also makes sense in that if $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective, then $A\le B$ and if it is surjective then $A\ge B$.

Answer (score 3):

An injection $A\to B$ provides a correspondence between $A$ and some subset of $B$ -- that, is an INjection points to a copy of $A$ INside $B$.

Comment: I'd replace "provides a correspondence" to "is a one-to-one correspondence". And the "copy of $A$" confounds me. I'd just say: "between $A$ and a some subset of $B$ -- that is, a set that is INside $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to remember is to only remember one, then by elimination you know the other.

I choose to remember injective as follows:

Injections cure things, and you have one injection for one cure.  I.e. one to one.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense since there could be many injections that cure the same disease.

Comment: Yes but you generally just get one.

Answer (score 1):

The way I remember them:

- An INjective function is INvertible (not strictly true, but it also helps me remember how to prove injectivity): Schematically, $f^{-1}(f(x) = f(y)) \implies x = y$
- A SURjective function is SURe to hit all the elements of the target.