# Mnemonic for Remembering Epic vs Monic

Tags: category-theory, mnemonic

I am trying to remember which arrows are epic (epimorphisms) and which arrows are monic (monomorphisms), but the terminology is very confusing. What is a hint/mnemonic for remembering which is which?

(Very Related: [Injection vs. Surjection: Mnemonic to remember which is which](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742152/injection-vs-surjection-mnemonic-to-remember-which-is-which))

Comment: Use them enough to where you don't have to think about it.  This goes for most pieces of terminology.

Comment: I see "monic" as having root "mono" or "one," and thus associate it with "one-to-one."

Comment: Similarly to @ThomasAndrews comment, the prefix "epi-" means "upon", which I can associate with "onto".